# This my laravell livewire project my all click function is not working but i render data on screen properly. how can i fix it?

Tags: php, laravel-livewire, livewires, laravel-9

> ```
> This is my livewire component class code
> ```

This is my livewire component class code
This is my livewire component class code This is my livewire component class code

```
  <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Livewire;
    use Livewire\WithPagination;
    use Livewire\Component;
    use App\Models\student;
    
    class Students extends Component
    {       
    
        public $selectData= true;
        public $createtData= false;
        public $updateData= false;
    
        public $name;
        public $email;
        public $country;
    
        public $studentID;
        public $edi_name;
        public $edi_email;
        public $edi_country;
    
        public $total_student;
        use WithPagination;
        
        public function render()
        {  $this->total_student=student::get();
            $student=student::orderBy('studentID','ASC')->paginate(100);
    
            return view('livewire.students',['student'=>$student])->extends('layouts.app');
       }
    
       public function showform()
       {
             dd('kawish');
           $this->selectData=false;
           $this->createtData=true;
       }
    
       public function resetField()
       {
           $this->$name="";
           $this->$email="";
           $this->$country="";
    
        $this->studentID;
        $this->edi_name="";
        $this->edi_email="";
        $this->edi_country="";
    
       }
    
       public  function create()
       {    
           $student=new student();
           $this->validate([
               'name'=>'required',
               'email'=>'required',
               'country'=>'required',
           ]);
```

//This is my livewire

```
           $student->name=$this->name;
           $student->email=$this->email;
           $student->country=$this->country;
    
           $result =$student->save();
           $this->resetField();
    
           $this->selectData=true;
           $this->createtData=false;
    
       }
       public function edit($studentID)
       {
        $this->selectData=false;
        $this->updateData=true;
    
        $student= student::findorFail($studentID);
        $this->studentID=$student->studentID;
        $this->edi_name=$student->name;
        $this->edi_email=$student->email;
        $this->edi_country=$student->country;
       }
       public function update($studentID)
       {
        
        $student= student::findorFail($studentID);
        $this->validate([
            'edi_name'=>'required',
            'edi_email'=>'required',
            'edi_country'=>'required',
        ]);
    
        $student->name=$this->edi_name;
        $student->email=$this->edi_email;
        $student->country=$this->edi_country;
        $result =$student->save();
        $this->resetField();
    
        $this->selectData=true;
        $this->updateData=false;
       }
       public function delete($studentID){
           $student= student::findorFail($studentID);
           $result=$student->delete();
    
       }
    }
```

//This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire //This is my livewire

> ```
> This is my view for the same class
> ```
>
> This is my view for the same classT his is my view for the same class

```
<div>
  @section('title','students')
     @section('content')


      <div class=" container">
        <div class="mt-5">
          <div class=" card">
            <div class=" card-header">
              <div class=" d-flex justify-content-between">
                <h3>users ({{count($total_student)}})</h3>
                <div>
                  <button wire:click='showform' class="btn btn-success">Add User</button> *//error
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

- List item

  ```
        {{-- table list --}}
        @if ($selectData==true) 
       <div class=" table-responsive mt-5">
         <table class="table table-bordered">
           <thead>
             <tr class="bg-dark text-light">
               <th>ID</th>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Email</th>
               <th>Country</th>
               <th>Options</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
           @forelse ( $student as $item )
            <tbody>
             <tr>
               <td>{{ $item->studentID }}</td>
               <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
               <td>{{ $item->email }}</td>
               <td>{{ $item->country }}</td>
               <td>
                 <button class="btn btn-success" wire:click="edit({{$item->studentID  }})">Edit</button>
                 <button class="btn btn-danger"  wire:click="delete({{$item->studentID  }})">Delete</button>
               </td>
             </tr>
             @empty
              <tr> 
                <td>
                 <p class="text-danger">#record not found</p>
                </td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
           @endforelse
           </table>
       </div>
       @endif


       {{-- create data --}}
     @if ($createtData==true)
     <div class="row">
       <div class=" col-xl-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 offset-xl-3 offset-md-2 offset-sm-0">
         <div class="card">
           <div class="card-header">
             <h1>Add Data</h1>
           </div>
           <form action="" class="mt-5" wire.submit.prevent='create'>
             <div class="card-body">
               <div class=" form-group">
                 <label for="name">Enter Name</label>
                 <input wire:model='name' type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                 <span class="text-danger">
                   @error('name')
                     {{ $message }}
                   @enderror
                 </span>
               </div>
               <div class=" form-group">
                 <label for="email">Enter Email</label>
                 <input wire:model='email' type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                 @error('email')
                     {{ $message }}
                   @enderror
               </div>
               <div class=" form-group">
                 <label for="country">Enter Country</label>
                 <input wire:model='country' type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                 @error('country')
                     {{ $message }}
                   @enderror
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class=" card-footer">
               <button class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
             </div>
           </form>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     @endif


       {{-- update data --}}
      @if ($updateData==true)
      <div class="row mt-5">
       <div class=" col-xl-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12 offset-xl-3 offset-md-2 offset-sm-0">
         <div class="card">
           <div class="card-header">
             <h1>Update Data</h1>
           </div>
           <form action="" class="mt-5" wire.submit.prevent='update({{$studentID}})'>
             <div class="card-body">
               <div class=" form-group">
                 <label for="name">Enter Name</label>
                 <input wire:model="edi_name" type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                 <span class="text-danger">
                   @error('edi_name')
                     {{ $message }}
                   @enderror
                 </span>
               </div>
               <div class=" form-group">
                 <label for="email">Enter Email</label>
                 <input wire:model="edi_email" type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                 <span class="text-danger">
                   @error('edi_email')
                     {{ $message }}
                   @enderror
                 </span>
               </div>
               <div class=" form-group">
                 <label for="country">Enter Country</label>
                 <input wire:model="edi_name" type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                 <span class="text-danger">
                   @error('edi_country')
                     {{ $message }}
                   @enderror
                 </span>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class=" card-footer">
               <button class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
             </div>
           </form>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
      @endif

     </div>
   @endsection
  ```

//This is my livewire //This is my livewire

> my layout codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <!-- CSS only -->
             <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
             integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
     @livewireStyles
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid bg-dark">
        <div class=" container p-4">
            <h2 class="text-center text-white">Laravel Livewire Crud</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

<div>
    @yield('content')
</div>
 
    @livewireScripts
</body>
</html>
```

> ```
> `**my routing**`
> ```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Http\Livewire\Students;


// Route::view('/', 'app');

Route::get('/', Students::class);
```

***here its endsssss***
here its endsssss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the @section in your component view. livewire component needs to start with a . You can extend your section inside the component to have it like this

```
  public function render()
        {  $this->total_student=student::get();
            $student=student::orderBy('studentID','ASC')->paginate(100);
    
            return view('livewire.students',['student'=>$student])->extends('layouts.app')->slot('content");
        }
```

You can have your component view like this

```
      <div class=" container">
        <div class="mt-5">
          <div class=" card">
            <div class=" card-header">
              <div class=" d-flex justify-content-between">
                <h3>users ({{count($total_student)}})</h3>
                <div>
                  <button wire:click='showform' class="btn btn-success">Add User</button> *//error
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```